# Why is the jQuery selector ':not' not working?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to select a div with an id or class and at the same time exclude a id or class inside the div and get the content as string.

Here is my markup:

```
<div id='main-content'>
  <div>test 1</div>
  <div class='ignore'>ignore test</div>
</div>
```

I tried `$('#main-content:not(.ignore)').text();`

It is selecting the div with the id main-content, but the class ignore is still in the string. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hsbnLu5j/).

Comment: You are saying that #main-content does not have the class

Comment: Please include all relevant code here on Stack Overflow, not only on another site. See [ask], where it says, "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but **also copy the code into the question itself**."

Comment: @Heretic Monkey Sorry, next time I will do that.

Answer (score 5):

You are selecting the element with the id and saying that should not have the class. It should be done on the child elements.

```js
console.log($("#main-content > *:not(.ignore)").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='main-content'>
  <div>test 1</div>
  <div class='ignore'>ignore test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thant you epascarello. So I was saying that I wanted to select the id "main-content" which didn't have the class "ignore". Damn, I thought it was selecting the id "main-content" without the content of the class "ignore". Thank you again.